# A non-blocking lock decorator in Python

Tags: python, concurrency

I needed to impose on a Python method the following locking semantics: the method can only be run by one thread at a time. If thread B tries to run the method while it is already being run by thread A, then thread B immediately receives a return value of `None`.

I wrote the following decorator to apply these semantics:

```
from threading import Lock

def non_blocking_lock(fn):
    fn.lock = Lock()

    @wraps(fn)
    def locker(*args, **kwargs):
        if fn.lock.acquire(False):
            try:
                return fn(*args, **kwargs)
            finally:
                fn.lock.release()

    return locker
```

This works in my testing so far. Does anyone notice any gotchas or have any suggestions for improvements?

### Revised version

After the suggestions by @RemcoGerlich, I have added a docstring and kept the lock local to the decorator:

```
from threading import Lock

def non_blocking_lock(fn):
    """Decorator. Prevents the function from being called multiple times simultaneously.

    If thread A is executing the function and thread B attempts to call the
    function, thread B will immediately receive a return value of None instead.

    """
    lock = Lock()

    @wraps(fn)
    def locker(*args, **kwargs):
        if lock.acquire(False):
            try:
                return fn(*args, **kwargs)
            finally:
                lock.release()

    return locker
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this will work fine and it's very close to how I would write it myself.

A few small things come to mind:

- There's no documentation of any kind that explains what the semantics are, and they're not explicit either (the return None if the lock isn't acquired is entirely implicit). I would put the short explanation you put in this question into a docstring, and/or add an explicit `else: return None` to the if statement.
- is there any reason why the lock object is exposed to the outside world by making it a property of the function (`fn.lock`) ? I would simply make it a local variable, so that it's hidden. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I’ve amended my original code and added it to the question, for posterity.